# Yii2 Redirect from A to B controller with URL modification

Tags: redirect, model-view-controller, url-rewriting, yii2, yii-url-manager

I want to redirect user from Controller A to controller B, call action view and send to it 3 params.

Also I want the url to look like `domain.com/param1/param2/param3`

Now I have the following.
Controller A.

```
return $this->redirect([$param1,$param2,$param3]);
```

urlManager in config

```
'<param1:\w+>/<param2:\w+>/<param3:\w+>' => 'B/view',
```

The result is dramatic :(
I see this in url , and blank screen

```
domain.com/A/param1?1=param2&2=param3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no route in your redirect, try this:

```
 return $this->redirect(['B/view',
    'param1'=>$param1,
    'param2'=>$param2,
    'param3'=>$param3]);
```